# Typescript understanding non assignable parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have the following

```
const client: Client | boolean = await db.connect()
if (client === false) {
  return
}

await start(client)
```

`db.connect()` either returns the client (on successful connect) or false (failed connect).

`start` only accepts `Client` as a param:

```
const start = async (dbClient: Client): Promise<void> => {
```

As you can probably see, I get an error with `await start(client)`:

> Argument of type true | Client is not assignable to type Client

I could get around this by specifying the type of `Client | boolean` in `start` and be safe knowing that it will never be false, since it returns early before `start` is called, and it will never be `true` since `connect` never returns true, but this smells (and could cause further issues down the line).

What's the best way/practice for this kind of thing?

Rather than just returning `Client` from `connect` I could return an object

```
{
  connected: boolean,
  client: client,
}
```

Does that make more sense here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you know it can only be Client or false you can encode that as a type `Client | false`. TypeScript is then smart enough to work out that if you exclude `false` whatever is left is `Client`.

```js
type ClientResult = Client | false;
const client: ClientResult = await db.connect()
if (client === false) {
  return
}

await start(client)
```

Comment: I tried that but I get 
`Type 'boolean | Client' is not assignable to type 'ClientResult'`
using

`type ClientResult = Client | false`
`const client: ClientResult = await db.connect()`

Comment: @CarlMarkham, what declaration for `db.connect()` function?

Comment: If I remove the return type from the `connect` method your solution works. So rather than `async connect(): Promise<Client | boolean> {` I now have `async connect() {`

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, both with and without a declaration for `connect()`:

```
interface Client {
    name: string
}

type ClientResult = Client | false

async function main() {
   const client: ClientResult = await connect(Math.random() > 0.5)
   if (client === false) {
      return
   }

    await start(client)
}

async function start(client: Client) {}

async function connect(i?) {
   return i ? { name: 'John' } : false
}
```

What version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: If you want to go down the complex object pathway, take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ghetto-monad. Disclaimer: I wrote that package myself to enforce null safety in a project I was on.